# postgresql help with php loop

Tags: php, postgresql

I keep getting an "Notice: Undefined index: did" error with this query, and I'm not understanding why...  I'm much more used to mysql, so, maybe the syntax is wrong?

This is the php query code:

```
function get_demos() {
        global $session;
        $demo = array();
        $result = pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT(did,vid,iid,value) FROM dv");
        if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($r = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                switch($r['did']) {
                    case 1:
                        $demo['a'][$r['vid']] = $r['value'];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $demo['b'][$r['vid']] = $r['value'];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $demo['c'][$r['vid']] = $r['value'];
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $session->session_setMessage(2);
        }

        return $demo;
    }
```

When I run that query at the pg prompt, I get results:

```
"(1,1,1,"A")"
"(1,2,2,"B")"
"(1,3,3,"C")"
"(1,4,4,"D")"
"(1,5,5,"E")"
"(1,6,6,"F")"
"(1,7,7,"G")"
"(1,8,8,"H")"
"(1,9,9,"I")"
"(1,10,A,"J")"
"(1,11,B,"K")"
"(1,12,C,"L")"
"(1,13,D,"M")"
"(2,14,1,"A")"
"(2,15,2,"B")"
"(2,16,0,"C")"
"(3,17,1,"A")"
"(3,18,2,"B")"
"(3,19,3,"C")"
"(3,20,4,"D")"
"(3,21,5,"E")"
"(3,22,6,"F")"
"(3,23,7,"G")"
```

Comment: try a `var_dump($r)` inside your while loop

Comment: Actually, figured out that the DISTINCT was what it wasn't liking...

Comment: Then please write an answer to your own question and accept it (after 48? hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [pg_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) function if you want to get associative array in $r.

Comment: pg\_fetch\_array() by default returns the numeric _and_ the associative indices, see http://docs.php.net/pg_fetch_array